# mysql using max as where condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I got 4 fields

```
page_id
page_category_id
page_sequence
page_path
```

For example

```
record 1

page_id = 1
page_category_id = 22
page_sequence = 1
page_path = "1.jpg"

record 2

page_id = 1
page_category_id = 22
page_sequence = 2
page_path = "2.jpg"

record 3   

page_id = 1
page_category_id = 23
page_sequence = 1
page_path = "23_1.jpg"

record 4
page_id = 1
page_category_id = 23
page_sequence = 2
page_path = "23_1.jpg"


record 5
page_id = 1
page_category_id = 23
page_sequence = 3
page_path = "23_1.jpg"

.. and more records
```

I want to do a draw statement that

```
$sql_select = "select page_category_id from my_table where max(page_sequence) < 3";
```

it will show all the page_category_id who max(page_sequence) is less than 3.

but I can't do it with max(page_sequence) as the where condition

How can I get it working.. **Thanks**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL is such fun, since you can almost always solve things in several completely different ways. Here's a `NOT EXISTS` alternative:

```
select distinct page_category_id
from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t2.page_category_id = t1.page_category_id
                    and t2.page_sequence >= 3)
```

Return a page_category_id if there are no row with same page_category_id that has a page_sequence >= 3.

Answer (score 1):

```
select page_category_id from my_table 
GROUP BY page_category_id 
HAVING max(page_sequence) < 2
```

Comment: you should write some explanation to the query.

Comment: @realnumber3012 don't link to some offsite source (even if it is the docs) without explaining. _Explain_ why this works for the OP. Also that link could eventually die (linkrot), so edit something in your question to explain.